# Rewrite to custom 404 page if .php is entered in the address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess file in my web server. It hides .php on all my files but if I go to page1.php it shows page1.php. I want it to rewrite to 404 page instead

Here's my htaccess file so far. it reoves .php and 404.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /spel/template/404
```